# Fast exponentiation implementation

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, exponentiation

Could someone please point out a site where I can find an algorithm to efficiently calculate integer exponentiation to large powers using C#?

eg. I want to calculate 2^60000 or 3^12345

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unless this is homework, you probably don't want to roll your own implementation of arbitrary precision exponentiation. Calculating large exponents of the type you describe is complicated - performance aside.

I would recommend using one of the [existing arbitrary precision arithmetic libraries, like GMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Multi-Precision_Library) - most of which have libraries to access them from C#.

F# has support for arbitrary precision arithmetic using the BigInt class (which you can also access from C# if you import the assembly it's in). However, I don't know how optimized BigInt exponentiation is.

If you're simply trying to learn about efficient algorithms for exponentiation, you may want to look into the [Square-And-Multiply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) algorithm for exponentiation.

Answer (score 2):

Integer exponentiation can effectively be calculated using a method known as "Exponentiation by squaring" [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

This method can also be used to calculate the modular exponentiation [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), which is used in some asymmetric encryption methods like RSA.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out: [IntX](http://www.codeplex.com/IntX/) for working with LARGE integers. You might have to write your own implementation of power, but since multiplication is supported, this should not be so hard.

Edit by 280Z28: Another implementation which includes fast Pow, ModPow, and primality testing is this [BigInteger](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx) implementation (Code Project), which I've used on Project Euler problems in the past - though I now work with .NET 4.0 and use its [System.Numerics.BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(VS.100).aspx) implementation.

Comment: I would advise using a more mature library than IntX if the results of the computations are at all important. Writing a correct library for arbitrary precision is harder than it looks - and many of the smaller projects out there have not yet had an opportunity to detect and resolve the types of problems that plague most implementations.